# json_normalize delivers ValueError, need of distinguishing prefix

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'd like to normalize JSON data in python using pandas and json_normalize.
Line 33 in the below code works fine. In line 36 I changed the last element to 'number' and get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Home/Downloads/JSONtoCSV/testflattening.py", line 32, in <module>
    print json_normalize(data, 'items', [['address','city'], ['address','company_name'], 'number'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/normalize.py", line 262, in json_normalize
    'need distinguishing prefix ' % k)
ValueError: Conflicting metadata name number, need distinguishing prefix
```

I think this is because the item 'number' is in conflict with internal variables of pandas. So I need to rename all 'number' items to something else.

I tried that in a first approach using the code in line 28 below - but I get the error message:

```
ValueError: 'number' is not in list
```

Sorry, but I am totally new to python - what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

```
import pandas

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

data = [{'address': {
                  'city': 'city A',
                  'company_name': 'company A'},
        'amount': 998,
        'items': [{'description': 'desc A1','number': 'number A1'}],
        'number': 'number of A',
        'service_date': {
                      'type': 'DEFAULT',
                      'date': '2015-11-18'},
        'vat_option': 123},
        {'address': {
                  'city': 'city B',
                  'company_name': 'company B'},
       'amount': 222,
       'items': [{'description': 'desc B1','number': 'number B1'},
                 {'description': 'desc B2','number': 'number B2'}],
       'number': 'number of B',
       'service_date': {
                     'type': 'DEFAULT',
                     'date': '2015-11-18'},
       'vat_option': 456}
       ]

data[data.index("number")] = "numbr"

print data

# working
#print json_normalize(data, 'items', [['address','city'],     ['address','company_name'], 'amount'])

# not working
#print json_normalize(data, 'items', [['address','city'], ['address','company_name'], 'numbr'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it - "number" seems so be not allowed with pandas. Changing all keys to e.g. "numbr" solves this issue:

```
eval(repr(data).replace("number", "numbr"))
```

Thanks to stackoverflow 46734293